# How to Load/Use two background's using HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

[Portfolio Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKHNA.jpg)

Hey Guys ! I am trying to create the Webpage like the image i attached above. i want it to be like , when i load or open the page then it should change the background or lower the opacity of the front background. is there any way to do that ?. Here it is what i have achieved so far. Thanks !

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    animation: loader 5s;
    
}
main {
    background:  linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(107, 11, 197),rgb(255, 139, 178));
    transition: 
    background 0.5s 2s;
}
main:hover {
    background: url(https://serving.photos.photobox.com/23831723b5e651e8ea16cd2216cb3c7400315d33c9c59fa7b3e662cb8698b88c4534825a.jpg);
}
/*@keyframes loader {
    0% {
        background: linear-gradient(150deg, rgb(107, 11, 197),rgb(255, 139, 178));
      }
      /* You could think of as "step 2" */
     /* 50% {
        background: url(img5.jpg);
      }
} */
.container{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
  
.left-column {
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 399px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.right-column {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float:right;
}
#img-profile {
    border-radius: 50%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
hr {
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
button {
    background-color: white;
    color: purple;
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    word-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Portfolio Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="left-column">
                    <div>
                        <h2>Hi, I'm Muhammad Sameem</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p style="color:yellow;">Web Developer</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>I spend time travelling arround the world, helping startups and tech businesses hire the best people.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button>GET IN TOUCH</button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: left; margin: 20px 10px 0px 0px;">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CS66DNX.png" alt="My Profile Picture" width="30" height="30">
                    </div>
                    <div style="float:left; margin: 20px 10px 0px 0px;">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IEYytth.png" alt="My Profile Picture" width="30" height="30">
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TiIwIJz.png" alt="My Profile Picture" width="30" height="30">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-column">
                        <img id="img-profile" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/088524356761d1a2116d1da8976d59a32f8e11850488cb2fdcd0503f605d169a02ac23b1.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" width="200" height="200px">
                </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: The code you've written looks fine, but the `container` block is containing `left-column` and `right-column` which are floating elements because of which the `container` is not taking whole space, try `100vh` or using `clearfix`.

Post it you can simple use a combination of background-image and background -color for what you are looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add background gradient using `:before` selector with opacity.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  animation: loader 5s;

}
main {
  background: url(https://serving.photos.photobox.com/23831723b5e651e8ea16cd2216cb3c7400315d33c9c59fa7b3e662cb8698b88c4534825a.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
main:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(107, 11, 197,0.9),rgba(255, 139, 178,0.9));
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}
main:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.container{
  width: 1100px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container:after{
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.left-column {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 399px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}
.right-column {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-top: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:right;
}
#img-profile {
  border-radius: 50%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
hr {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
button {
  background-color: white;
  color: purple;
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Portfolio Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="left-column">
                <div>
                    <h2>Hi, I'm Muhammad Sameem</h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="color:yellow;">Web Developer</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>I spend time travelling arround the world, helping startups and tech businesses hire the best people.</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button>GET IN TOUCH</button>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; margin: 20px 10px 0px 0px;">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/CS66DNX.png" alt="My Profile Picture" width="30" height="30">
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; margin: 20px 10px 0px 0px;">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IEYytth.png" alt="My Profile Picture" width="30" height="30">
                </div>
                <div style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/TiIwIJz.png" alt="My Profile Picture" width="30" height="30">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="right-column">
                <img id="img-profile" src="https://serving.photos.photobox.com/088524356761d1a2116d1da8976d59a32f8e11850488cb2fdcd0503f605d169a02ac23b1.jpg" alt="Profile Picture" width="200" height="200px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this lines to your code, under main:hover;

```
transition: 0.2s;
opacity: 0.6;
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
 <style> 
        #ex1{
            background-image: url(demo1.gif), url(demo2.gif);
            background-position: right bottom, left top;
            background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
            padding: 15px;
         }
 </style>





<div id="ex1">
        use multiple background
</div>
```

Comment: but i want the first one or upper one to be of lower opacity like in the image attached